# Java Make Event for xscreensaver

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

How to make Java app, that will catch screen activation event on Ubuntu (`xscreensaver`)?

The program should execute some function, when screen wake up from `xscreensaver` blankscreen or when `xscreensaver-command -deactivate` was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple.

Just run a command `xscreensaver-command -time` to get current status of `xscreensaver`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ xscreensaver-command -time
XScreenSaver 5.42: screen blanked since Tue May  5 15:46:46 2020
```